# selenium get the <div> count inside another <div>

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have to get the count of number of div inside another div
My HTML code is like

```
<div id="list">
<div> some_data </div>
<div> some_data </div>
<div> some_data </div>
<div> some_data </div>
<div> some_data </div>
</div>
```

I tried with the code:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='list']")).size());
```

But getting result: 1 instead of 5

Is their any other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with the x-path `//*[@id='list']/div` as given below

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='list']/div")).size());
```

Comment: What about the python version?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='list']/div"));
```

Now you have a list of divs, This list is nothing but an interface of collection interface.
Now you can perform multiple operations on it.Like

```
elements.get(int index);  
elements.clear();
elements.isEmpty();
elements.size();
```

and many more.

Hope this will help